# Terminal: du -sm

Tags: command-line, du

I have to complete some activity for my university and I need to know what does the command `du -sm`.I have already searched in many websites but i didnt find the answer.
Could you help me?

Comment: In a terminal, you can read the manual for every command through `man <command_name>`, in your case `man du`. Use this hint to go futher in your activity.

Comment: `man du` will tell you all you are seeking to find

Comment: This looks a lot like a homework question. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/du-command-linux-examples/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read about things like this with `man` by using

```
man du
```

there it says

> du - estimate file space usage

> -m
> like --block-size=1M

> -B, --block-size=SIZE
>
> scale sizes by SIZE before printing them; e.g., '-BM' prints sizes in units of 1,048,576 bytes; see SIZE format below

> -s, --summarize
> display only a total for each argument

A single `-` usually indicates single character parameters while `--` can be whole words. so when there are multiple characters after a single `-` it is usually a combination

Comment: Yeah, I saw that but just now I'm getting that it's a combination of -m and -s flags. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes! A single `-` indicates single character parameters while `--` can be whole words. so when there are multiple characters after a single `-` it is always a combination

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Comment: You're welcome. If this solved your question you can tick the anwser to indicate this question as closed and my anwser as helpfull.

Comment: @totalynotanoob some commands (e.g. `find`) use a single `-` for whole words (e.g. `find -name`)

Comment: @MaxSilvester Oh thanks I was not aware of this. I changed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Du_(Unix)) on Wikipedia
or you can use

```
du --help
```

to get information about the command.

Content of help command:

```
Usage: du [OPTION]... [FILE]...
  or:  du [OPTION]... --files0-from=F
Summarize disk usage of the set of FILEs, recursively for directories.

Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.
  -0, --null            end each output line with NUL, not newline
  -a, --all             write counts for all files, not just directories
      --apparent-size   print apparent sizes, rather than disk usage; although
                          the apparent size is usually smaller, it may be
                          larger due to holes in ('sparse') files, internal
                          fragmentation, indirect blocks, and the like
  -B, --block-size=SIZE  scale sizes by SIZE before printing them; e.g.,
                           '-BM' prints sizes in units of 1,048,576 bytes;
                           see SIZE format below
  -b, --bytes           equivalent to '--apparent-size --block-size=1'
  -c, --total           produce a grand total
  -D, --dereference-args  dereference only symlinks that are listed on the
                          command line
  -d, --max-depth=N     print the total for a directory (or file, with --all)                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                          only if it is N or fewer levels below the command                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                          line argument;  --max-depth=0 is the same as                                                                                                                                                                                                         
                          --summarize                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
      --files0-from=F   summarize disk usage of the                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                          NUL-terminated file names specified in file F;                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                          if F is -, then read names from standard input                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  -H                    equivalent to --dereference-args (-D)                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  -h, --human-readable  print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)                                                                                                                                                                                                
      --inodes          list inode usage information instead of block usage                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  -k                    like --block-size=1K                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  -L, --dereference     dereference all symbolic links                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  -l, --count-links     count sizes many times if hard linked                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  -m                    like --block-size=1M                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  -P, --no-dereference  don't follow any symbolic links (this is the default)                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  -S, --separate-dirs   for directories do not include size of subdirectories                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      --si              like -h, but use powers of 1000 not 1024                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  -s, --summarize       display only a total for each argument                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  -t, --threshold=SIZE  exclude entries smaller than SIZE if positive,                                                                                                                                                                                                         
                          or entries greater than SIZE if negative                                                                                                                                                                                                             
      --time            show time of the last modification of any file in the                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                          directory, or any of its subdirectories                                                                                                                                                                                                              
      --time=WORD       show time as WORD instead of modification time:                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                          atime, access, use, ctime or status
      --time-style=STYLE  show times using STYLE, which can be:
                            full-iso, long-iso, iso, or +FORMAT;
                            FORMAT is interpreted like in 'date'
  -X, --exclude-from=FILE  exclude files that match any pattern in FILE
      --exclude=PATTERN    exclude files that match PATTERN
  -x, --one-file-system    skip directories on different file systems
      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit

Display values are in units of the first available SIZE from --block-size,
and the DU_BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE and BLOCKSIZE environment variables.
Otherwise, units default to 1024 bytes (or 512 if POSIXLY_CORRECT is set).

The SIZE argument is an integer and optional unit (example: 10K is 10*1024).
Units are K,M,G,T,P,E,Z,Y (powers of 1024) or KB,MB,... (powers of 1000).

GNU coreutils online help: <http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/>
Full documentation at: <http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/du>
or available locally via: info '(coreutils) du invocation'
```